# Ubuntu on Toshiba U920T/023?

Tags: toshiba-satellite

all

Thinking of getting Toshiba  Satellite U920T/023. This is a tablet with sliding keyboard and is bundled with horrible Windows 8.

Did anyone try to install Ubuntu on it and get it to work as tablet and as a laptop?

Thanks,
Rudolf

Answer (score 0):

I installed ubuntu after tweaking a few hours with UEFI (boot-repair doesn't work you need to manually change the Windows boot file in /EFI/Boot with the grub one). For daily usage it's perfect, it's fast and touchscreen gestures work (even if sometimes when you use both touchpad and touchscreen at a certain point touchscreen starts hovering instead of clicking)! I suggest you install Google chrome since firefox doesn't support touchscreen devices yet. The only thing that still doesn't work are the brightness control keys which I can't use since the fn-keys map is partially wrong.